# Lower bounds on $\sum_i^d p_i (1-p_i)^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convex-analysis

I'm interested in getting bounds on the following summation for fixed discrete probability distribution $p_i$ over $d$ outcomes with $p_i>0$ and arbitrary $k>1$

$$f(k)=\sum_{i=1}^d p_i (1-p_i)^k$$

I can get upper bounds by applying Jensen's inequality to subsets of numbers, which gives me a family of cheap upper bounds.

$$\sum_i^s a_i^k\le \left(\sum_i^s a_i\right)^k$$

Is there a good family of cheap lower bounds? Especially for the case when $k\approx d$ and $d$ is large.

Motivation: I'm using root finder to solve for $\sum_i^d p_i (1-p_i)^k=b$ for this [application](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2362355) which is too expensive
because $d$ is large, so I want to speed it up by finding bounds first

Comment: Can $p_i=0$ for some $i$?

Comment: These are eigenvalues of random graphs, hence pretty unlikely

Comment: And are we summing over all values? i.e., $p_1+\cdots+p_d=1$?

Comment: Yes, updated the question

Comment: I'm not sure how to attack something like this, but I suspect the [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) should be helpful.

Comment: Because you have a large but finite population of values of $p$, might simple random sampling (or some more efficient random sampling approach) allow for finding bounds for the sum?  That certainly makes for a "data dependent" approach.

Answer (score 2):

The lower bound is unfortunately $0$. Indeed, let
$p_1=p_2=\dots=p_{d-1}=0$,
and $p_d=1$. Of course, you require them to be all positive, but you can make them very very small, and the last one to be close to one.

By the way, there's a nice upper bound using the fact that
$$
\sup_{p\in[0,1]} p(1-p)^k=\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d p_i(1-p_i)^d\le \frac{k^k d}{(k+1)^{k+1}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks although I'm looking for data-dependent lower bounds. IE, computing $f(k)$  for $d$ values of $k$ takes $O(d^2)$ time, I was looking at some way to do it in $O(d\log d)$ using cheaper to compute bounds that depend on $p_i$

Comment: Cross posted on [dsp.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/86922/discrete-version-of-this-transform), it's is the same question because $(1-p_i)^k\approx \exp(-k p_i)$ in my application

Comment: The denominator should be $(k+1)^{k+1}$ since the supremum is obtained at $p=1/(k+1)$.